how to retrieve all the text (including the tags/child_elements) from an element using lxml
xml_content = <root><para>Brother set had private his letters observe outward resolve. Shutters ye marriage to throwing we as. <child1>Effect in if agreed he wished wanted admire expect</child1>. Or shortly visitor is comfort <child2>placing to cheered do</child2>. Few hills tears are weeks saw. Partiality insensible celebrated is in. Am <child3>offended as wandered</child3>thoughts greatest an friendly. Evening covered in he exposed fertile to. Horses seeing at played plenty nature to expect we. Young say led stood hills own thing get</para></root>.
Hi, I would like to slurp everything with in the <para> and be able to access Young with in the para. the lil script I have got gets only until "Brother set had private his letters observe outward resolve. Shutters ye marriage to throwing we as."
this is my script :
parser = ET.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
root = ET.XML(xml_content, parser=parser)

# Function to deep copy an element
def get_deep_copy(element):
    return copy.deepcopy(element)

# Extract and print the <para> elements
new_para_elements = [get_deep_copy(para) for para in root.findall('.//para')]

# Printing the lxml elements
for elem in new_para_elements:
    print(elem.text)

Please note I need the tags to be accessible as elem.tag as I have to make further decisions based on the occurrence of a particular  tag say child3.

it may need to iterate child elements in para and remove or keep them. But if you want to keep information about tags then it would need to keep as a tree or nested lists - and this may need complex code to create it, and complex code to work with it.

There are perhaps other tree models like XDM that might be more convenient to process such mixed content with XQuery 3.1 and/or XSLT 3.0 and/or XPath 3.1. Supported in Python with e.g. saxonche https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/ and for XPath 3.1 also with https://pypi.org/project/elementpath/. But in all cases you will need to traverse the tree structure and extract the data you need.

In the data model used by lxml, the piece of text that contains "Young" is the tail of the <child3> element. The text is not a property of the parent <para> element.

Problem is that HTML/XML has complex structure with nested elements (children which may have own children). It hard to convert it to different structure - so maybe it is better to keep it as is.
lxml has function .iter() to run for-loop on all nested elements but you have to get .text and .tail to have full content and iter() may give result in wrong order.
To get correct order it may need to use nested for-loops without iter() - but for more complex structure it may need to use recursion
Here code for your example data. I added more nested element <extra> with nested <abc> to show problem with more complex structure.
It shows all versions - with .iter(), with nested for-loops, with recursion.
xml_content = """<root><para>Brother set had private his letters observe outward resolve. Shutters ye marriage to throwing we as. <child1>Effect in if agreed he wished wanted admire expect</child1>. Or shortly visitor is comfort <child2>placing to cheered do</child2>. Few hills tears are weeks saw. Partiality insensible celebrated is in. Am <child3>offended as wandered</child3>thoughts greatest an friendly. Evening covered in he exposed fertile to. Horses seeing at played plenty nature to expect we. Young say led stood hills own thing get
<extra>12<abc>34<xyz>HELLO</xyz>56</abc>78</extra>90
</para></root>"""

import lxml.etree as ET
import copy

parser = ET.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
root = ET.XML(xml_content, parser=parser)

new_para_elements = [copy.deepcopy(para) for para in root.findall('.//para')]

print('\n--- version 1 - iter() ---\n')

for elem in new_para_elements:
    print(f'{elem.tag} text:', elem.text or "")
    
    for child in elem.iter():
        print(f'  {child.tag} text:', child.text or "")
        print(f'  {child.tag} tail:', child.tail or "")
    
    print(f'{elem.tag} tail:', elem.tail or "")

print('\n--- version 2 - nested for-loops ---\n')

for elem in new_para_elements:
    print(f'{elem.tag} text:', elem.text or "")
    
    for child in elem:
        print(f'  {child.tag} text:', child.text or "")
        for child2 in child:
            print(f'     {child2.tag} text:', child2.text or "")
            print("TODO: add here another nested `for`-loop")
            print(f'     {child2.tag} tail:', child2.tail or "")

        print(f'  {child.tag} tail:', child.tail or "")
    
    print(f'{elem.tag} tail:', elem.tail or "")

print('\n--- version 3 - recursion ---\n')
    
def display(item, indention=0):
    spaces = " " * indention
    print(f'{spaces}{item.tag} text:', item.text or "")
    for child in item:
        display(child, indention+4)
    print(f'{spaces}{item.tag} tail:', item.tail or "")    
    
for elem in new_para_elements:
    display(elem)

Result:
--- version 1 - iter() ---

para text: Brother set had private his letters observe outward resolve. Shutters ye marriage to throwing we as. 
  para text: Brother set had private his letters observe outward resolve. Shutters ye marriage to throwing we as. 
  para tail: 
  child1 text: Effect in if agreed he wished wanted admire expect
  child1 tail: . Or shortly visitor is comfort 
  child2 text: placing to cheered do
  child2 tail: . Few hills tears are weeks saw. Partiality insensible celebrated is in. Am 
  child3 text: offended as wandered
  child3 tail: thoughts greatest an friendly. Evening covered in he exposed fertile to. Horses seeing at played plenty nature to expect we. Young say led stood hills own thing get

  extra text: 12
  extra tail: 90

  abc text: 34
  abc tail: 78
  xyz text: HELLO
  xyz tail: 56
para tail: 

--- version 2 - nested for-loops ---

para text: Brother set had private his letters observe outward resolve. Shutters ye marriage to throwing we as. 
  child1 text: Effect in if agreed he wished wanted admire expect
  child1 tail: . Or shortly visitor is comfort 
  child2 text: placing to cheered do
  child2 tail: . Few hills tears are weeks saw. Partiality insensible celebrated is in. Am 
  child3 text: offended as wandered
  child3 tail: thoughts greatest an friendly. Evening covered in he exposed fertile to. Horses seeing at played plenty nature to expect we. Young say led stood hills own thing get

  extra text: 12
     abc text: 34
TODO: add here another nested `for`-loop
     abc tail: 78
  extra tail: 90

para tail: 

--- version 3 - recursion ---

para text: Brother set had private his letters observe outward resolve. Shutters ye marriage to throwing we as. 
    child1 text: Effect in if agreed he wished wanted admire expect
    child1 tail: . Or shortly visitor is comfort 
    child2 text: placing to cheered do
    child2 tail: . Few hills tears are weeks saw. Partiality insensible celebrated is in. Am 
    child3 text: offended as wandered
    child3 tail: thoughts greatest an friendly. Evening covered in he exposed fertile to. Horses seeing at played plenty nature to expect we. Young say led stood hills own thing get

    extra text: 12
        abc text: 34
            xyz text: HELLO
            xyz tail: 56
        abc tail: 78
    extra tail: 90

para tail: 

